# Can't seem to connect to an Iframe with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.6

The id of the iframe seems to be dynamic( seems to be change with a refresh?), so I'm only connecting with it temporarily and can't perform any calls (all results are an empty list). So I'm attempting to see the contents of iframe, but it's also resulting in an error. Is there a way I can connect to the iframe and perform calls on it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://investsnips.com/list-of-publicly-traded-micro-cap-diversified-biotechnology-and-pharmaceutical-companies/')
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tradingview_4e896"]')
time.sleep(20)
#driver.switch_to.frame("tradingview_21872")
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[1]   # 0 is resulting in an error
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
iframe.tag_name
```

Is resulting in the error:

`StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <iframe id="tradingview_d311f"> stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed`

Comment: if you are providing a single element by giving index then why are using `find_elements`

Comment: you can try something like : `for i in range(1,20): driver.switch_to_frame(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch to iframes, there are 3 ways to achieve this task.

**1. By using Index of iframe**

Looking on the webpage, I see that there are 4 iframes on the page, and you are interested in the 3rd one (with index = 2). So you can use

`driver.switch_to_frame(2)`

**2. By using name or ID of iframe**

Since the iframe doesn't have a `name` field, and doesn't have a unique `id`, this option is useless in this scenario.

**3. By using WebElement of iframe**

You can fetch the `iframe` as a `WebElement` and then switch focus to it. The WebElement of the `iframe` can be fetched using the xpath `"//iframe[contains(@id, 'tradingview')]"`

Comment: really? coz this xpath works for me. you can either edit my answer with the correct xpath or post it in comments so I can improve my answer. This way it can be marked accepted

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer and provided a different way as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do get it to work by copying the Xpath via Chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('http://investsnips.com/list-of-publicly-traded-micro-cap-diversified-biotechnology-and-pharmaceutical-companies/')
time.sleep(20)


x= driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/iframe')

driver.switch_to_frame(x)
```